# Python Insertion sort algorithm doesn't arrange floating point numbers in file properly

Tags: python, floating-point, insertion-sort

My algorithm places some numbers in my file incorrectly, for example: 10015.0 before 1006.8765

```
#My insertion sort algorithm
    def insertion_sort(float_list):
        for i in range(1, len(float_list)):
            key = float_list[i]
            j = i-1
            while j >= 0 and key < float_list[j]:
                float_list[j+1] = float_list[j]
                j -= 1
            float_list[j+1] = key
        return float_list

#Turning strings in file into floats
     with open("floats.txt", "r") as f:
        lst = f.read().splitlines()
        [float (i) for i in lst]
        print(lst)
    
    insertion_sort(lst)
    print(lst)

#writing into new file    
    with open("sorted_floats.txt", "w") as sorted_floats:
        sorted_floats.write(str(lst))
```

Comment: You should include an example of `lst` in your [mre].  We don't have access to your text  file - how can we help?

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't do anything: `[float (i) for i in lst]`

Because you aren't converting your inputs from strings to floats, your code is sorting the lines of the file alphabetically rather than numerically.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: Yes, convert the input data from strings to floats before trying to sort them.

Comment: Thanks I changed it to lst = [float (i) for i in lst] and it worked. Cheers.